# Loading an image from Dropzone.js into Tensorflow.js

Tags: dropzone.js, tensorflow.js

Currently, we are having an issue where we need to allow a user to drop an image into the initial landing page, then when they press the `Identify!` button, it takes the image that is currently in the dropped image location and then throw it into the model to then be predicted.

The **issue currently** is figuring out how to put the image that has just been thrown into the Dropzone to be processed and then put into our model for prediction.

```
let identify = document.querySelector('.identify')
if (identify) {
    identify.addEventListener('click', event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        let user_pic = document.querySelector('.dz-image').children[0].src
        ...
        const prediction = model.predict(user_pic)
        console.log('This is your prediction: ', prediction)
    })
}
```

What is happening is that the console is saying:
`Uncaught TypeError: model.predict is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>`

Which doesn't make sense as we have the CDN Tensorflow tag in our template, so it should work appropriately.

Comment: What are you assigning to model ?

Comment: The initial variable is `const model = tf.loadLayersModel('model_json')`

Comment: You need to use "await"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `await` since loading the model is an asynchronous operation

```
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('model_json')
```